# RAID 6, 2 disk fail, while third was rebuilding

Tags: network-attached-storage, raid6

I have Infortrend DS S16E-G2152-6 NAS, 16 4TB drives (WD4000FYYZ) in RAID 6. Last week one drive failed, was replaced and was rebuilding. At around 80% of rebuild, another two drives failed simultaneously.

Controller reset was waking up one of the failed drives, but recovery again failed.

One of failed drives will be now professionally cloned to very similar new drive. I am hoping I can just stick it in the array and NAS will think it is the old drive that works and start rebuild (I assume it will see only 1 failed drive and one clean).

Are my assumptions correct? Do NAS check for filesystem and data on the drive to know if it is one from the unit, or serial number and firmware? Or any other thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from Infortrend support, saying that it will work, NAS is doing data check.

Today I got back the cloned disk, put it in, reset controller and recovery is under way.

Will post final result if it works.

PS: It worked flawlessly, so there is hope!

Answer (score 0):

> Are my assumptions correct?

There's no blanket right or wrong answer, it depends on the NAS and the specific situation.

> Do NAS check for filesystem and data on the drive to know if it is one
>   from the unit, or serial number and firmware?

Again so do, some don't, there' literally no way of knowing without one of us on here having that exact model and having had to do something similar in the past.

Or any other thing?

You've not really given us anything to go off, though my first thought would be a) you've had a lot of bad luck here, what exact make and model are the disks, I think this would put us all off using them in the future and b) the best anyone here will have to offer is the suggestion to just wipe and restore from last backup - it might sound glib but it's one of our most used expressions on serverfault as it's often the quickest way to fix any potential data-loss situation.

Comment: I hope anybody has experience with this unit. We will see, otherwise I will provide the answer in a few days.

Drives are WD 4TB Enterprise Storage, in yellow color (WD4000FYYZ as I have mentioned). Doubt I will use them again, probably going to check what is best today.

Bad luck and not changing the dead drive right away and waiting a week before doing so. Lesson learned.